# When identifying final state particles do they include the results of any intermediary or additional decay?

Tags: particle-physics

I am looking for a clarification of what exactly the term **final state particles** include. Say I have the reaction
$$Z \to e^+ + e^-$$
So my final state particles would be $e^+$ and  $e^-$ correct?
But if I have a something like this
$$z \to \mu^+ + \mu^-$$
where 
$$\mu^+ \to e^+ + \nu$$
Would my final state particles in that case include the $e^+$ and neutrino?

Comment: As you found out by yourself, the term **final state particles** is not really uniquely defined, as you can always have follow-up reactions. Thus, it depends on the context.

Answer (score 1):

For experiments , it depends on what one is studying. One uses known measurable final particles, and stops there , unless in your example one wants to study once more muon decays.

Muons live long enough to be measurable in the laboratory. Note that the neutrino is not measurable and in this case one has to assume the Z properties, not look for the Z.